# SimpleForm post form to differnt controller and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have Event show page where I display a customer form for `@customer`. If the event is a different kind of an event then I display a form for @registration and I want to post that form to RegistrationsController#create.

Right now in my routes I have this:

#### routes

```
post '/:slug' => 'events#create', as: :registration
```

#### form

```
<%= simple_form_for @registration, url: custom_registration_path, html: { class: 'form, styled-form', autocomplete: 'off' } do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

The form above still posts to `EventsController#create`
I define @registration in `EventsController#show` and I want to post the form to custom_registration_path.

How do I define the route? I still want to send the `:slug` to RegistrationsController.

Comment: Does it work better with `post '/:slug', to: 'registrations#create', as: :custom_registration` ?

Comment: question is not clear.Tell me  which controller and action should be trigger for form submit?

Comment: You can start your debugging with looking up the result HTML `<form>` tag and checking out the `action` attribute. If it has a proper URL then there's something wrong with routes (You can use `rake routes` to debug them)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. I have updated my question. So the problem is the route, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the situation correctly:
You can't have two routes with the same HTTP method & path. The `method + path` combination has to be unique.
You either should route your custom registration to smth like `custom_registrations/:slug` or change the path for `events#create`

Of course, you can use a different method for different actions. `PUT` for example. But I'd consider it a bad practice as it's very implicit and will be hard to understand for anyone working with this code.